# What is the most efficient way to load data from a backend when an app opens?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm utilizing Parse as my backend and it seems like sometimes the table loads up and sometimes I have to manually refresh to show my information.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
self.loadObjects()

}
```

Is this the only way to accomplish that feat. Again, sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't. It's very spotty and quite odd. The weird thing is that all subsequent reloads once the app runs, whether a user makes a new post or something similar, are instant and never miss.

loadobjects is a Parse function, its documentation says the following.

```
/*!
 Clears the table and loads the first page of objects.
*/
- (void)loadObjects;
```

Alternatively, this code is also available for use

```
   /*!
 Loads the next page of objects, appends to table, and refreshes.
 */
- (void)loadNextPage;
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `loadObjects()`? Normally if you have a networked backend, you'll want to load on a background thread, and callback to the main/UI thread for an update or refresh.

Comment: @CraigOtis added up.

Answer (score 2):

`-viewWillAppear` does not get called if your app is already running. (i.e. the app was in the background and you're now returning to it)
Take a look at the `UIApplicationDelegate` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowinng the code for loadObjects(), think you probably run a parse asynchronous query in there. If not you probably should. In the completion block of such query, after updating your data model, call tableView.reloadData(). This usually works for me and you should see the cells "popping" up one by one.

Edit: further look at the documentation for PFQueryTableViewController shows that there is an objectsDidLoad method that you can override. Put tableView.releadData() in there and don't forget to call super.objectsDidLoad. This might solve but I have not tried myself.